# Node hierarchy from directory path list

Tags: kotlin

Hi I'm trying to build a node hierarchy based on the directory structure:

```
 /first/
 /first/second
 /first/third
 /first/third/forth
 /first/third/fifth
 /first/sixth
 /first/sixth/seventh
 /first/eighth
 /first/ninth
```

I'm trying to get a node hierarchy similar to this:

```
first
  second
  third
    forth
    fifth
sixth
  seventh
eighth
ninth
```

I'm using Kotlin for this, I'm still relatively new to Java and Kotlin so bear with me.

Note: I'm using FileTreeWalk to get the directories

```
fun getDirs(directoryName: String): MutableList<String> {
    val ret = mutableListOf<String>()

    File(directoryName).walk().forEach {
        if (it.isDirectory) { ret.add(it.toString()) }
    }    

    return ret
}
```

Right now all I have is this (Generates a flat hierarchy):

```
private fun nodesFromPathList(dirPaths: MutableList<String>) : Tree.Node {
    val ret = Tree.Node("root")

    for (dir in dirPaths) {
        ret.add(Tree.Node(dir))
    }

    return ret
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put all the nodes into a map and connect the nodes together.

```
 /**
 * Creates a node hierarchy from list of paths
 */
private fun nodesFromPathList(dirPaths: MutableList<String>) : Tree.Node? {
    var ret : Tree.Node? = null
    val nodeMap = mutableMapOf<String, Tree.Node>()

    // Add a node for each directory path and put it into a map
    for (dir in dirPaths) {
        val newNode = Tree.Node(nodeName(dir), skin)
        if (ret == null)
            ret = newNode

        nodeMap.put(dir, newNode)
    }

    // Go through each one and add the child
    nodeMap.forEach {
        val parent = parentPath(it.key)

        try {
            nodeMap[parent]!!.add(it.value)
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
            println("Parent not found")
        }
    }

    return ret
}

/**
 * Returns current path
 * "D:\dir\to\apath" ==> "apath"
 */    
fun nodeName(path: String): String {
    return path.split("\\").last()
}

/**
 * Returns the parent path
 * D:\dir\to\apath ==> D:\dir\to
 */
fun parentPath(path: String): String {
    val split = path.trim('\\').split("\\")
    var ret = ""
    for (i in 0..split.size-2) {
        ret += split[i] + "\\"
    }

    return ret.trim('\\')

}
```

I put the path into the key, and the tree node into the value. Iterated through the map and connected the children based on the parent. Example Map.:

```
[D:\android\assets=Tree$Node@56eb1af5,
D:\android\assets\Assets\abc=Tree$Node@48e3456d,
D:\android\assets\Assets\abc\bcd=Tree$Node@3e532818,
D:\android\assets\Assets\abc\cde=Tree$Node@16b07083]
```

I would find the parent from the key (by splitting the string), then set the parent.